# show element on click if button is in component A and element is in component B

Tags: html, angular, typescript

**I want to show div when button is clicked but they both are in different components. So how to interact between components.**

*I am very new to angular4 so if there is any better way to do this i will really appreciate it*

### These are two different components html.

> button.component.html

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" [hidden]="hidden" 
      (click)="hidden = true ">Show Age</button>
```

> text.component.html

```
     </div> AGE </div>
    <div *ngIf="hidden"> 22 </div>
```

### Adding screenshot

[image]

Comment: Are the components siblings?

Comment: NO they're not @User3250

Answer (score 2):

Your **Component A** should have an output event:

```
@Output() change = new EventEmitter();
// ...
onClick(){
  this.change.emit();
}
```

And emit it on click on the button:

```
<button (click)="onClick()">Show Age</button>
```

And your parent component *(= the component that contains **A** and **B**)* should take care of the `hidden` value, pass it to the **Component B** and change it when it receives the `change` event from the **Component A**.

**Parent Component HTML:**

```
<app-component-a (change)="hidden = !hidden"></app-component-a>
<app-component-b [hidden]="hidden"></app-component-b>
```

**Parent Component TS:**

```
hidden:boolean = false;
```

**Component B TS:**

```
@Input() hidden:boolean = false;
```

Comment: Thanks Maarti . I know the way is correct but this is not working for me.